# Difference in pronunciation between "вce" and "вcё"?

Tags: перевод, буква-ё

Ran into the two words "вce" and "вcё". The teacher I have pronounces the words exactly the same even though the last letter is different.

I also ran the word through the Google Translate and some other fifth class software and got what appears to me as the same pronunciation for both of them or garbage.

Are the words pronounced the same? Do you guys have an opinion and expertise about this?

Comment: If your teacher pronounces them the same, fire this teacher.

Answer (score 5):

These words actually have both different meanings and different pronunciation.
Transcriptions are the following:

Все - [ф с' э]

Всё - [ф с' о]

Comment: Except the first consonant is really pronounced 'F', not 'V'.

Comment: this is only the part of the answer, the other one is that de-facto "е" is quite often used as "ё" . Plus yes, you transcription is wrong and well, better to use international one.

Comment: @VictorBazarov, thanks for the comment. Really, it's been a while since I used this notation last time :)

Comment: @shabunc what "international one"? There is no "international one", suitable for Russian.

Comment: @Anixx - so, you believe that IPA is not enough for Russian?

Comment: @shabunc IPA is totally irrelevant for Russian. Not to say it is intended to describe phones rather than phonemes. If one wants to learn Russian he has to learn Russian transcription first.

Answer (score 4):

Listen to audios, or read IPA transcriptions, at the wiktionary article for [все](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5#Pronunciation).  The first one is the pronuncation of `все`, the secons one is pronuncation of `всё`.

Note that in Russian ё is often written as е, so the word written as `все` may actually mean `всё`.  Such ё->е replacement is most common in printed books, newspapers and journals (almost 100% cases), common in Internet (50% cases), and less common, but still ocasionally happens, in handwritten texts.